# What's the syntax for using IFS and datevalue in ArrayFormula?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a source sheet with a column of dates. on sheet2 I tried to create a column in which each cell contains a number. The number came from converting the dates on source sheet after evaluate them using `IFS`. here is my code that works on each individual cell when not combine with array formula:

```
=ifs(AND(Source!A2>DATEVALUE("05/06/2019"),Source!A2<=DATEVALUE("06/15/2019")),949,AND(Source!A2<=DATEVALUE("05/06/2019"),Source!A2>=DATEVALUE("04/01/2019")),900,Source!A2>DATEVALUE("06/15/2019"),999,true,)
```

However, when I tried to combine `arrayformula` I got error saying the Array arguments to `IFS` are of different size:

```
={"header name here";ArrayFormula(ifs(AND(Source!A2:A>DATEVALUE("05/06/2019"),Source!A2:A<=DATEVALUE("06/15/2019")),949,AND(Source!A2:A<=DATEVALUE("05/06/2019"),Source!A2:A>=DATEVALUE("04/01/2019")),900,Source!A2:A>DATEVALUE("06/15/2019"),999,true,))}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ARRAYFORMULA` does not understand `AND` so you need to convert it into 0/1 logic:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((Source!A2:A> DATEVALUE("05/06/2019")) * (Source!A2:A<=DATEVALUE("06/15/2019")), 949,
 IF((Source!A2:A<=DATEVALUE("05/06/2019")) * (Source!A2:A>=DATEVALUE("04/01/2019")), 900,
 IF((Source!A2:A> DATEVALUE("06/15/2019")), 999, ))))
```

[image: 0]

---

alternative approaches: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**

Comment: It was very useful for me as well. Thank you very much!
Why did they do it